# Empty response from Parse.com - Anyone having trouble?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm noticing some requests sent to Parse are getting empty responses. Here's an example:

push data={'channels': ['psg-status', 'manchester-city-status', 'panchicore-a'], 'data': {'action': 'status', 'badge': 'Increment', 'payload': {'name': u'PSG vs Manchester City', 'text': u'Fin del primer tiempo: PSG 1-1 Manchester City', 'team_b_channel': 'manchester-city-status', 'object_id': 93311, 'team_a_channel': 'psg-status', 'action': 'status', 'notification_type': 'match_halftime_starts'}, 'objectId': 93311, 'alert': u'Fin del primer tiempo: PSG 1-1 Manchester City'}} headers={'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': ‘XXXXX’, 'X-Parse-Application-Id': ‘XXXXX’, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} [url=https://api.parse.com/1/push]

**Response is 200 but content instead of a “{"result":true}” is “”**

Anyone having a similar problem?

After parse.com's announcement, has anyone noticed abnormalities in their service?